# String manipulation with curly brackets in bash

Tags: bash, string, variable-substitution

I have a string from a latex file that I would like to work on:

```
\title{This is the title}
```

I would like to save "This is the title" in a variable, but cannot manage to remove the substrings with the curly brackets, despite my attempts of escaping these.

```
title=`grep -F "\title" file.tex`
title=${title#\}}
title=${title%\{}
```

Neither of these work, and putting the curly brackets in single or double quotation mark doesn't either.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have GNU grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$title` is the string `\title{This is the title}`:

```
title=${title#*{}
title=${title%\}}
```

The `{` in the first parameter substitution does not need to be escaped (escaping it won't make it not work though), but the `}` in the second needs escaping.  In the first one, you additionally need `*` to match the `\title` bit in the string, alternatively use `${title#\\title{}` to delete the explicit string `\title{`.

You seem to get the `%` and `#` mixed up in your code, and you forgot the `*` in the substitution that removes the prefix string.

---

Assuming no title string spans more than a single line, you may get all those strings out of a document with

```
sed -n 's/.*\\title{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/p' file
```

This matches (the first) `\title{SOMETHING}` on each line, and replaces the whole line with the `SOMETHING` substring.  All other data is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash, you can use its regex facilities instead:

```
title='\title{This is the title}'
[[ $title =~ \{(.*)\} ]] && title=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo "title=$title"

title=This is the title
```

That's, assuming you really need to do this in bash. If that stuff comes from a file, you better use tools better suited to extract and parse data from files, like `grep`, `awk`, `perl`, or `tex` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to do this in the shell. Just parse the output of `grep` before saving in a variable:

```
title=$(grep -F '\title' file.tex | sed s'/.*{\(.*\)}/\1/')
```

or

```
title=$(grep -F '\title' file.tex | awk -F'[{}]' '{print $2}')
```

Or, if you have GNU `grep`, or any other implementation that supports `-o` and `-P`, you can do:

```
title=$(grep -oP '\\title\{\K[^}]+' file.tex)
```